# What is the fastest pitch ever recorded in MLB?

Tags: mlb

I am seeing online that there are a lot of people who state Aroldis Chapman is the hardest throwing pitcher, and I am also seeing a lot of people who state that Nolan Ryan holds that record. Both with some staggering numbers, which is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on how you measure stuff. It's generally accepted that MLB's current tracking system ([PITCHf/x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PITCHf/x)) is the most accurate system available, and Chapman holds the record for a PITCHf/x measured pitch with his [105 mph pitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3wJ-HgsnCg) on 2010-09-24 for the Reds vs the Padres.

Various people have attempted to translate older measurements into the same standards as used by PITCHf/x, notably the fact that PITCHf/x measures the speed of the pitch 50 feet from home plate. For example, [eFastball](http://www.efastball.com/baseball/stats/fastest-pitch-speed-in-major-leagues/) estimate that Ryan's pitch on 1974-20-08, which was measured at 100.9 mph at a point 10 feet from home plate would have been travelling at 108.1 mph at the PITCHf/x measurement point of 50 feet from home plate, and thus is faster than Chapman's pitch. But this is an estimate, not a measurement so should be taken with a (small) grain of salt.

Answer (score -4):

It seems that Aroldis broke his own record a few weeks ago (Check that up [here](http://m.mlb.com/statcast/leaderboard#pitch-velo)!).

It's worth it that Aroldis Chapman is by far the pitcher with most 100+ ptiches in 2015 and since 2010.

https://twitter.com/BtBScore/status/622807554809163776

Comment: How is "103.9 mph" faster than "105 mph"?

Comment: It depends on what Cameron is asking for. You have pitch speed and perceived speed (https://youtu.be/d44acFJ0gqk). If we take into account pitch speed, my answer is wrong and the pitch Aroldis thrown against the Padres is fastest, but it's quite different if we have a look at the perceived speed column. Even if we go to that date (24/10/2010), it's not clear the speed of that ptich as there were there measurements of the pitch (http://fantasysportsadvice.sportsblog.com/posts/2831507/mlb-s-fastest-pitch-ever-recorded.html). May be the question should be asked in a different way.